# R-markdown interpreting all code as String

Tags: r, r-markdown

I've put some code in R-markdown. When saving as PDF it interprets all this code as String, so it has green color. How can I fix this?

````
```R
datos_limpieza <- function(dataframe) {
  dataframe <- dataframe[-c(nrow(dataframe), nrow(dataframe) - 1),-ncol(dataframe)]
  colnames(dataframe)[which(names(dataframe) == "X1")] <- "Comunidad Autónoma"
  dataframe[is.na(dataframe)] <- 0
  dataframe$`Comunidad Autónoma` <- gsub("\\d+ ", "", dataframe$`Comunidad Autónoma`)
  comunidades_correccion <- list(
    c("Asturias, Principado de", "Principado de Asturias"), 
    c("Balears, Illes", "Islas Baleares"), 
    c("Canarias", "Islas Canarias"), 
    c("Castilla - La Mancha", "Castilla-La Mancha"), 
    c("Comunitat Valenciana", "Comunidad Valenciana"), 
    c("Madrid, Comunidad de", "Comunidad de Madrid"), 
    c("Murcia, Región de", "Región de Murcia"), 
    c("Navarra, Comunidad Foral de", "Comunidad Foral de Navarra"), 
    c("Rioja, La", "La Rioja"))
  i = 1
  for (comunidad in dataframe$`Comunidad Autónoma`) {
    for (par in comunidades_correccion) {
      if (comunidad == par[1]) {
        dataframe[i, 1] <- par[2]
      }
    }
    i <- i+1
  }
  dataframe[19, 2:ncol(dataframe)] <- 
    dataframe[19, 2:ncol(dataframe)] + dataframe[20, 2:ncol(dataframe)]
  dataframe[19, 1] <- "Ceuta y Melilla"
  dataframe <- dataframe[-20, ][order(dataframe[-20, ]$`Comunidad Autónoma`), ]
  rm(i, comunidades_correccion)
  return(dataframe)
}
```
````

Result:

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ntwjw.png)

Comment: Try starting the code chunk with ```{r}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was the letter "ó", probably because the ´.

Answer (score 2):

Start the R-markdown code blocks with:

````
```{r}

code here

```
````

Comment: I tried, but I don't want to execute the code, so I put it as {r eval=FALSE}. Unfortunately the issue still happens, it seems to be with the line:

`colnames(dataframe)[which(names(dataframe) == "X1")] <- "Comunidad Autónoma"`

If removed, everything is fine.

Answer (score 1):

The very first line of your code ```` ```R ```` should be written with brackets, as ```` ```{r} ````.
You can keep the rest of it as the same. Putting it in brackets specifies the language engine for R to use.

You can see other language engines available in Rmarkdown here if you are curious
https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/language-engines.html